# Using CMake and Boost, Targets may link only to libraries, Cmake is dropping the Item

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have been trying to install Boost onto my CLion IDE using Cmake. I have manually set my Boost CMake variables as shown:

```
         set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Users/Ethan/BoostFolder/boost_1_75_0/boost_1_75_0)
         set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR C:/Users/Ethan/BoostFolder/boost_1_75_0/boost_1_75_0/libs)
```

No errors pop up. But this warning here:

```
          WARNING: Target "BoostTest" requests linking to directory "C:/Users/Ethan/BoostFolder/boost_1_75_0/boost_1_75_0/libs".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
```

Prevents me from using Boost in my CLion files.

Here is my Complete CMakeLists.txt file, I guess I shouldn't be manually specifying the Boost variables, but I'm in a rush to get to use it.

```
          cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
          project(Lantern)

          set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)






    add_executable(Lantern
    BattleManager.h
    CharacterComponents.h
    CMain.c++
    CTests.cpp
    CTree.h
    GameCharacters.h
    GameCommands.h
    GameStructure_main.h
    GameUtilities.h CPlayGround.cpp CPlayGround.h)

   set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Users/Ethan/BoostFolder/boost_1_75_0/boost_1_75_0)
   set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR C:/Users/Ethan/BoostFolder/boost_1_75_0/boost_1_75_0/libs)

  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  add_executable(BoostTest CPlayGround.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(BoostTest ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
```

Answer (score 3):

In this line you are telling CMake to link your executable target `BoostTest` to a directory:

```
target_link_libraries(BoostTest ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
```

What you want to do is use the [`FindBoost`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html) machinery by going through `find_package`:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED <components>)
```

Where  is a list of Boost libraries you need.
Then you can link your application to Boost by doing

```
target_link_libraries(BoostTest Boost::boost)
```

and adding any other non-header Boost libraries to that list.
The page linked above explains that the two variables you set are used as hints (and/or output) of the `FindBoost` scripts.

Comment: ok, I remembered a `boost_with_libs` shortcut, that I believe does the same thing. (I may be wrong)  and when trying to build, I received this error: `Could NOT find Boost (missing: assert) (found version "1.75.0")`

Comment: Then either you didn't set the hints correctly and it can't find Boost at all (setting `Boost_ROOT` to `C:/Users/Ethan/BoostFolder/boost_1_75_0/boost_1_75_0` should be what you need) or you are requesting non-header-only libraries and haven't built Boost yet.

Comment: should i be concerned that the CMake states  `New Boost version may have incorrect or missing dependencies and imported targets?`  And  
  `No header defined for assert; skipping header check (note: header-only
  libraries have no designated component)` what does cmake mean?

Comment: The first thing just says your CMake does not know about Boost version 1.75 yet (although I thought it was Boost that supplied the script, not CMake). If it works, it works. The second is saying that you can't "find" the `assert` library because it's header-only and doesn't have to be specified in the call to `make_package`.